# Git autocomplete in screen on mac os

Tags: git, macos, gnu-screen

I've using git on mac and I have configured autocompletion as written at http://www.codethatmatters.com/2010/01/git-autocomplete-in-mac-os-x/ It works fine when I do it in pure terminal.

But I prefer to use gnu screen program when working in terminal. And in screen when I press tab noting happen. Maybe someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: You might check and see if `screen` is running the same shell as you normally use in the terminal.

Comment: "echo $SHELL" shows /bin/bash both in pure terminal and in screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use `screen` but I think it will probably work if you put the `source ~/git-completion.bash`
 statement in your ~/.bashrc instead of your ~/.bash_profile.  I don't think `screen` counts as a login shell.

Comment: You are right! =) I've did "ln -s .bash_profile .bashrc" and everything wokrs like a charm. Thank you!