# Screen and Cygwin: no tab completion?

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen

I'm having some problems working with my development environment. Specifically, after I invoke the screen utility from within Cygwin I lose the ability to do tab completion. Before I invoke screen however tab completion works just fine.

I messed around with setting different values for the TERM env variable (VT100, xterm etc) but without success. It must be something trivial but I have no idea anymore. Does StackOverflow have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 4):

when you issue 'screen' from inside cygwin it might put you in another shell like /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash (and bash is where you're getting the tab completion from).

To fix the problem you could edit your .screenrc file (found in your home directory) and add in this line:

```
shell bash
```

Then try running screen again and you should see tab completion work within this new window.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that bash needs to be run as a login shell in order to have tab completion in the default cygwin setup. If you run `bash` in a cygwin bash you won’t have tab completion either. To set screen to run bash in login mode, add this line to your ~/.screenrc file:

```
shell -bash
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with git autocompletion not working when using screen on a linux machine, but wasn't due to a different shell. I fixed it using this question: [Git autocomplete in screen on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911771/git-autocomplete-in-screen-on-mac-os) and doing the following:

Get the git autocompletion script

```
curl https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -OL
```

why would you want that hanging around?

```
mv git-completion.bash .git-completion.bash
```

add this line to your ./bashrc

```
source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Then in your terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That worked for me.

(I imagine after three years you've probably solved your problem, but I hope this helps someone else)

Comment: Hello Nicholas and welcome to SO. Thx for putting effort into such an old question... Your answer significantly adds good info to the question. hence my upvote.

Comment: Thanks! SO has helped me innumerable times in the last few years, I'm looking forward to giving something back to the community.